# XSL 1.0 difference of two node sets

Tags: xslt, set, difference

I have got an XML file with a structure similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <medias>
  <media>
    <id>34500</id>
    <refid/>
  </media>
  <media>
    <id>34501</id>
    <refid>34500</refid>
  </media>
  <media>
    <id>34502</id>
    <refid>34500</refid>
  </media>
  <media>
    <id>34503</id>
    <refid>34501</refid>
  </media>
 <media>
    <id>34504</id>
    <ref/>
 </media>   
 <media>
    <id>34505</id>
    <refid>34502</refid>
 </media>   
</medias>
```

With XSL 1.0, I want to access all nodes that are not referenced by others.
So I created two variables

```
<xsl:variable name="origID" select="media/id/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="refID" select="media/refid/text()"/>
```

and looked up on how to perform a difference operation between these two element sets

```
<xsl:variable name="diffID" select="$origID[count(. | $refID) != count($refID)]"/>
```

The result was:

*origID contains 34500, 34501, 34502, 34503, 34504, 34505*

*refID contains 34500, 34500, 34501, 34502*

I expected that

*diffID would contain 34503, 34504, 34505*

but

*diffID still contains 34500, 34501, 34502, 34503, 34504, 34505.*

What would be the best approach to accomplish my objective to get all nodes whose ID is referenced by other nodes.

Thanks in advance

Andre

Comment: Andre please post your XSLT. Thank you, Peter

Comment: thanks for the hint Peter. I did not notice that the XSLT was missing in the final post. I had the tags already in my question but did not format it as code so they were hidden in the frontend view. Now it should work.

Comment: No problem, I saw you got answers back already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ids which are not referenced by an refid into a variable you may try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="diffID" select="media[not(id = //media/refid)]/id"/>
```

To show that it work use:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="diffID" select="media[not(id = //media/refid)]/id"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$diffID" >
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Which will generate the following output.

```
34503, 34504, 34505,
```

If the real file is far bigger you should use `xsl:key`

And to do the same with id's in variables:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="origID" select="media/id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="refID" select="media/refid"/>
    <xsl:variable name="diffID" select="$origID[not(. = $refID)]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$diffID" >
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's real magic. Great. Thank you very much for the example!

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use the `except` operator (as long as you select nodes and not primitive values):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="medias-with-id" select="//media[id]"/>
<xsl:variable name="referenced-medias" select="key('by-id', //refid)"/>

<xsl:key name="by-id" match="media" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$medias-with-id except $referenced-medias"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```